# PHP Mysql Laravel eloquent error because of slashes in string, Can't remove slashes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How to make this: 
Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [$all_users])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
to produces this correct query: 
update `users` set `disabled` = 1, `users`.`updated_at` = '2020-01-03 14:11:09' where `user_id` not in ('642','532','539','588','488','601')

**I can't get rid of the slashes.**

The string is build like this: $all_users=$all_users.$user_id->id."','";

If I print $all_users string, it prints correctly, see below 
echo $all_users; 
produces: 
'642','532','539','588','488','601'

Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [addslashes($all_users)])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
produces: 
update `users` set `disabled` = 1, `users`.`updated_at` = '2020-01-03 13:53:02' where `user_id` not in **('\'642\',\'532\',\'539\',\'588\',\'488\',\'601\'')**

Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [$all_users])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
produces: 
update `users` set `disabled` = 1, `users`.`updated_at` = '2020-01-03 14:11:09' where `user_id` not in **('\'642\',\'532\',\'539\',\'588\',\'488\',\'601\'')**

//also I tried this
//Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [$all_users])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
//Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [removeslashes($all_users)])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
//Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [addslashes($all_users)])->update(['disabled' => 1]);
//Users::whereNotIn('user_id', [str_replace("","\", $all_users)])->update(['disabled' => 1]);

Thanks !

Comment: Eloquent uses parameterized queries, aka prepared statements.  Understanding that may lead you to understand why your string is being encoded as ONE parameter for safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an array not a string

```
$all_users[]=$user_id->id;

Users::whereNotIn('user_id', $all_users)->update(['disabled' => 1]);
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you !